# Regex: find words following on "^\w+\s+" - New Syntax Definition (MMIX) - Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, syntax, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3, mmix

I am trying to create a **syntax definition** file for the [MMIX](http://mmix.cs.hm.edu/) assembler language. These files are used by *Sublime Text 3* to highlight the syntax of a text/source file and as of late are written in *YAML*.

Instructions that follow on `^\s+` are highlighted correct, `^\s+ADD\s+` for example.
[image: Instruction following on white space]
(f.l.t.r: Syntax definition file, MMIX source)

However, instructions **following a label and white space** get not highlighted alone, but rather everything from the beginning of the line to end end of the regexp gets highlighted.

`^\w+\s+IS\s+` does not work right.
[image: Instructions following a label and white space]

I recently learned some theory about regular expressions, but never have used them on a computer.

**How can I achieve, that only the token `IS` gets highlighted?**

Comment: Would you mind sharing the syntax definition if you still have it? I'd be really happy if I don't need to write my own... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **Positive Lookahead**, try the following.

```
IS(?=\s)
```

Comment: It works nearly perfect, but a line starting with `IS` is not allowed, but gets highlighted by the expression. I tried to append a `+`, `IS(?=\s+)` but that does not work. Is it possible to fix that case with that notation?

Comment: No, that does not work. Nothing gets highlighted any longer. I triple checked the spelling, so no typos. :-) The syntax for `IS` has to be `[someAlphanumericLabel]\s+IS\s+`. `\s*IS\s+` is not allowed.

Comment: By trying I figured out, that `\s+IS(?=\s)` works. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, you helped me a lot!